# JMenuItem can be added to JMenu after that JMenu was added to JMenuBar?

Tags: java, swing, menu

Having this swing app:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

        // JMenu added to JMenuBar BEFORE JMenuItem
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        JMenuItem loadItem = new JMenuItem("Load");
        JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        fileMenu.add(loadItem);
        fileMenu.add(saveItem);
        fileMenu.add(exitItem);


        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }
}
```

that correctly displays the menu bar, where the order is JMenuBar > adding JMenu > adding JMenuItem. But this modification does not works:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

        JMenuItem loadItem = new JMenuItem("Load");
        JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        fileMenu.add(loadItem);
        fileMenu.add(saveItem);
        fileMenu.add(exitItem);

        // JMenu added to JMenuBar AFTER JMenuItem
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }
}
```

where the order is JMenuBar > adding JMenuItem > adding JMenu. Of course adding JMenuItem to `new`ed JMenu is just preperation before that JMenu will be added to JMenuBar. But it still does not work. Why? Does the order to adding one another matters?

PS: this question was asked because after building the app several times, it sometimes shows the menubar, and other times does not show the bar at all (i.e. blank frame). I firstly thought it has to do with the order of adding the objects, but even in the other case (when JMenu is added AFTER JMenuItem) it worked. And other time the first case did not work. It is weird, but at the moment I dont know what it is causing

PS2:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    public MyFrame(){
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried several permeations of your code without been able to replicate the issue, which makes me think there is something in your `MyFrame` class which may be contributing to your issue

Comment: @user85421 I'd be more inclined to call `revalidate` on the `rootPane` as it's the container which is actually responsible for managing the menu bar - but that's me.  `JFrame` has a complex hierarchy, which is one of the many reasons why it's generally discouraged to extend directly from it

Comment: @user85421 Sure - but `JFrame` is a the container which is managing the root pane.  Developers are more likely to extend from `JFrame` then `JRootPane` which places them into a difficult starting place.  Much simpler to start with a `JPanel` or some such - makes the component more re-usable and doesn't tightly couple you to a one window type or use case. But as I've already said, I'm unable to reproduce the OPs problem based on the available information, so calling `revalidate` may not even work, not that's a bad suggestion with the available information - I'm just saying

Comment: I have added the implementation of `MyFrame`. It is really tiny wrapper around `JFrame`

Comment: @user85421 Again - this whole mess is one of the many reasons we generally discourage extending from `JFrame`, I know you never said anything about extending from it, I'm just highlighting some of the pitfalls - do you call revalidate on the frame of the root pane!?

Comment: @milanHrabos The "simple" answer to your problem would be to not call `setVisible(true);` on your window until AFTER you've completed establishing it's content, this will solve a multitute of your issues.  Call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the window, the root pane or the menu bar for me had the same result as doing nothing - for me, the menu bar would appear momentarily after the window was established, this could just be a side effect of the system and my hardware - again, call `setVisible` last - solve lots of problems.

Comment: @user85421 First relax, I'm not accusing you of anything, I'm simple highlighting why the community will often discourage users from extending from top level containers that's all

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks. Adding `setVisible(true)` at the end of the code resolved the issue and now the program works correctly everytime. This is accepted answer (comment)